# How to click a link element programmatially with HTMLElement?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, webforms

I'm doing an automation program. I load a webpage into my windows form and load it in WebBrowser control. Then, I need to click on a link from the WebBrowser programatically. How can I do this? for example:

1. `<a href="http://www.google.com">Google Me</a>`
2. `<a href="http://www.facebook.com" id="fbLink">Facebook Me</a>`

The above are 2 different conditions. The first element does not have an `id` attribute while the second one does. Any idea on how to click each programmatically?

Comment: what do you mean by clicking Programmatically?

Comment: the program will automatically click the link. Clicking programmatically means it is clicked by program,but not clicked by user

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to find your element first, by its ID or other filters:

```
HtmlElement fbLink = webBrowser.Document.GetElementByID("fbLink");
```

And to simulate "click":

```
fbLink.InvokeMember("click");
```

An example for finding your link by inner text:

```
HtmlElement FindLink(string innerText)
{
    foreach (HtmlElement link in webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"))
    {
        if (link.InnerText.Equals("Google Me"))
        {
            return link;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i can't implement this code under axwebbrowser event. i try to debug it using breakpoint,but i found out it will automatically stop at "foreach (HtmlElement link in webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"))". do u know what's going on?

Comment: mshtml.HTMLDocument htm = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)axWebBrowser1.Document;

                foreach (HtmlElement link in htm.getElementsByTagName("a"))
                {
                    if (link.InnerText.Equals("Advanced search"))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("yea!!");
                    }
                }

Comment: Its very old post still I want to know why I am getting `webBrowser.Document` as `null` always and how to handle `DocumentCompleted` event.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to automate the browser then.

One way to do this is to use Watin (https://sourceforge.net/projects/watin/). It allows you to write a .Net program that controls the browser via a convenient object model. It is mainly used to write automated tests for web pages, but it can also be used to control the browser.

If you don't want to control the browser this way then you could write a javascript that you include on your page that does the clicking, but I doubt that is what you are after.

Comment: thx for your reply ,Rune. However ,i m writing the automation function by myself using axWebBrowser. but i face the problem of clicking the link :(

Comment: @DEN If such a simple task is a problem that's a strong argument for using a library instead.

Comment: Not sure if that was ever watin's domain, but its not any more.  Its now only located at http://watin.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: The link in this answer leads to some man offering to get rich fast.. Current link https://sourceforge.net/projects/watin/

Comment: This is a six year old answer, so I'm not sure if it's relevant anymore, but I fixed the link anyhow. Thanks!