# How to InvokeMember using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, authentication, html-agility-pack

I want to use `HtmlAgilityPack` class to login. But I don't know how.

This is what I've tried. But it's not working.

```
txtUserName.Text = "username";
txtPassword.Text = "password";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlWeb().Load("about:Tabs");
doc.GetElementbyId("username").SetAttributeValue("value", txtUserName.Text);
doc.GetElementbyId("password").SetAttributeValue("value", txtPassword.Text);
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//button[@class='btn login-btn blue pull-right btn-primary']"))
 {
    node[0].InvokeMember("click");//wrong code
 }
```

I **cannot** use `WebBrowser` class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clicking button automatically using HtmlAgilityPack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563901/clicking-button-automatically-using-htmlagilitypack)

Comment: but no answer for question and example
please way for code top without WebBrowser class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to login using `Selenium` and I think it's the best way to do it:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("Your Address Login");
IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Id("username"));
query.SendKeys("Your Username");
query = driver.FindElement(By.Id("password"));
query.SendKeys("Your Password");
query.Submit();
```

download [selenium for dotnet](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.48/selenium-dotnet-2.48.0.zip)

After download add reference `WebDriver.dll` and use namespace `OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;`

Learn more [Here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org)

Answer (score 0):

HtmlAgilityPack can only parse html.

Use WebClient instead.

Comment: thanks for answer please example code up by Use WebClient

Comment: @Sezar - google! search this forum - PLENTY of examples. did you read the documentation? No? Here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx :-)