# How to invoke Click using HTML AGILITY PACK

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, html-agility-pack

In **WebBrowser**( WEBFORMS) we can i `InvokeMember("click")` when we parse an HTML.
How can we do this using **HTML AGILITY PACK** .

```html
<a id="ctl0_CONTENU_PAGE_resultSearch_PagerTop_ctl2" href="javascript:;//ctl0_CONTENU_PAGE_resultSearch_PagerTop_ctl2">
```

How can i use HTTP REQUEST when we have a javascript in Href.

Answer (score 4):

No htmlagiliypack is not a html rendering engine you cannot invoke a click event . It 's `just a parsing tool`
use `Webbrowser` or `selenium webdriver` if you want

Comment: I don't need authenfication I have just to go to the next page.
For WebBrowser it's for WinForm can't use it in  ASP.net MVC

Comment: web browser is just an activex and is used in many application in windows so you  can use it with any html page you want

Comment: This is the Error when i tried to use Webbrowser :

Unable to instantiate ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' because the current thread is not a single-threaded apartment (STA) thread.

Comment: try to reproduce the issue and post  your code is the best way to have a solutiion

Comment: I reposted the problem here 
[WebBrowser in ASP.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43674732/webbrowser-in-asp-net)

Comment: I'm waiting you to answer  so I can accept this as a solution.
Thank you

Comment: I gave you an answer

Answer (score 1):

HtmlAgilityPack is only used to parse HTML and it doesn't support invoking events.

To invoke events you could use WebClient to send HTTP Request or Selenium.

For Selenium you could check this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34244583/7827699

For How to send Http Requests using WebClient:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't need authenfication I have just to go to the next page.

Comment: can you tell more details please ? are you using WinForms ? What do you mean by "authentication"? and if you just want to go the next page why wouldn't you simply do a redirect with the url that you have?

Comment: it's the same url(It's like a partial View ) ; i edit my question; the Href is a javaScript Function so i can't get the url.
HTML:
<a id="ctl0_CONTENU_PAGE_resultSearch_PagerTop_ctl2" href="javascript:;//ctl0_CONTENU_PAGE_resultSearch_PagerTop_ctl2"></a>
When i click the html table changes its value but we stay in the same page.

Comment: So basically you are trying to call a JavaScript function from the server side, right?

Comment: And if you tried to use the webbrowser activex control, what problem did u exactly have?

Comment: This error : 

"Unable to instantiate ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' because the current thread is not a single-threaded apartment (STA) thread."