# Browser Automation using C# - Write & Read

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I've found and tested an `HTML Agility Pack` program that scrapes the objects of a select element from a website which is really cool and useful but I want to also be able to write to the website.

This is the website I want to automate:
http://www.lookupwarranty.com/

**I have 2 goals:**

1. Auto select a manufacturer and enter a serial number with user input (write)
2. Read the Date Purchased and Warranty Expiration

This would have to be done in C#, and since I'm a newbie to this, I haven't been able to find the right documentation to write to this website using `HTML Agility Pack`. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might be able to do this either with the methods I'm currently trying or with any other methods? Any tips would be great!

Comment: Close duplicate: [Clicking button automatically using HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563901/clicking-button-automatically-using-htmlagilitypack). In a nutshell, HTML Agility Pack is generally intended for parsing of HTML only. Use Selenium or another similar browser automation library to accomplish this.

Comment: @esqew Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Selenium with C# to do this, not sure if `HtmlAgilityPack` supports UI interacting.

Comment: Thank you for the help!